# Why do I have a red envelop every time I come to Programmers?

Tags: support, notifications

Multiple times a day on Programmers, I'm lulled into a false sense of popularity when I'm presented with a red envelop in the middle of the top bar. But when I click through, I see that I don't have any messages. Multiple times a day.

I don't experience this on Stack Overflow. Does anyone else get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever one of the questions you've starred has new activity, the envelope lights up. By the looks of it, [you have a few very popular questions starred](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/8575/chrisaycock?tab=favorites), which is why you see it light up every time you visit.

Comment: Hmm ok. But why is Recent always blank? There's nothing on Recent to indicate anything at all has happened, much less activity on a starred question. It's just really confusing to see it perpetually lit-up.

Comment: @chrisaycock Favorite changes don't show up on the summary. [It's confusing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=envelope), I'm not going to lie, but you *should* see a red number on one of the tabs when the envelope lights up, even if the summary is blank. Clicking on the tab with the red number will show you what's changed.

Comment: Oh, I see I can turn-off favorites notification in preferences. Thanks, this should solve it.